# Failed: Expected one matching request for criteria "Match URL method: GET" found none

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

Hello I am trying to make mock GET call of an APIin my jasmine unit test, it is returning me url not found error.

I did this in service.spec file :

```
it('GET call for store details API', waitForAsync(inject([HttpTestingController, AuthService],
        (httpClient: HttpTestingController, authService: AuthService) => {

            var obj = {
                "IsSuccess": true,
                "Result": [
                    {
                        "Details": "Test"
                    }
                ]
            }

            authService.getStoreDetails()
                .subscribe((get: any) => {
                    expect(get).toBe(obj);
                });

            const successRequest = httpTestingController.expectOne(environment.baseUrl1 + '/api/details/10/0');
            expect(successRequest.request.method).toEqual('GET');
            successRequest.flush(obj);
            httpTestingController.verify();
        })));
```

When I am doing the same thing in other GET call without multiple endpoints `ex; api/user` , then the test is working fine. What is the solution for this and also with GET using certain params ?

**EDIT:-**

*Adding service.ts*

```
createId() {
    const ids = localStorage.getItem('ids');
    return ids
}

// GET API for Store Details
  getStoreDetails(): Observable<any> {
    let headers = this.createAuthrorizationHeader();
    let idd = this.createId();
    var id = Number(JSON.parse(idd!));
    return this.http
      .get(`${environment.baseUrl1}/api/details/${id}/0`, { headers: 
      headers })
      .pipe(tap(res => {
        console.log(res);
        retry(2),
          catchError(this.handleError)
      })
      )
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your URL is wrong for `expectOne` or maybe it's not a `GET` request.

To debug, try this:

```
it('GET call for store details API', waitForAsync(inject([HttpTestingController, AuthService],
        (httpClient: HttpTestingController, authService: AuthService) => {

            var obj = {
                "IsSuccess": true,
                "Result": [
                    {
                        "Details": "Test"
                    }
                ]
            }
            // Edit - add this line
            localStorage.setItem('ids', '10')

            authService.getStoreDetails()
                .subscribe((get: any) => {
                    // expect(get).toBe(obj);
                    expect(1).toBe(1);
                });

            // const successRequest = httpTestingController.expectOne(environment.baseUrl1 + '/api/details/10/0');
            // expect(successRequest.request.method).toEqual('GET');
            // successRequest.flush(obj);
            // log out the URL you expect
            console.log('url: ', environment.baseUrl1 + '/api/details/10/0');
            httpTestingController.verify();
        })));

    afterEach(() => {
      // clear local storage so it does not leak for other tests
      localStorage.clear();
    });
```

The `httpTestingController.verify()` should detect if there are any HTTP calls in progress that have not been dealt with (not flushed).

If there are, it will tell you the URL that was not flushed and you should use this URL for the `expectOne`.

If there aren't, you have a bigger problem in which `authService.getStoreDetails()` does not make an API call.

That should hopefully help you debug.

Edit: I see the issue, most likely `ids` is undefined in localStorage and you have to set this item.

Comment: Tried your debug code and I am still failing `Error: Expected no open requests, found 1: GET https://the-url/api/details/0/0` <--- the endpoints are changed to 0/0 no idea for what reason

Comment: Yes, so you have to find out why the `10` is getting changed to zero. Should hopefully be relatively easy.

Comment: is this some backend issue ? I don't think Jasmine will do this stuff. First time I faced this error

Comment: Show the `authService` class. I think it should be the one making the API call for the URL.

Comment: Added in EDIT section of question. And no it's not the one which is making call pretty sure it is /10/0. I am getting success response in code as well as in POSTMAN.

Comment: Check out my edit, it is most likely that `localStorage` is undefined for `ids`.

Comment: Tried with the local storage , working fine now. Thanks !